# select highest value without using max

Tags: sql, select

Please, how can i have the same result from my select without using MIN/MAX function?
I need the vendedor_nome and the highest venda_valor from table venda

```
CREATE TABLE Vendedor(vendedor_id integer, vendedor_nome text);

CREATE TABLE Venda(venda_id integer, vendedor_id integer,vendedor_data date,
venda_valor double);

INSERT INTO Vendedor VALUES(1,'Joao');
INSERT INTO Vendedor VALUES(2,'Maria');
INSERT INTO Vendedor VALUES(3,'Pedro');

INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(1,1,'2016-01-01',5000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(2,1,'2016-08-01',2000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(3,1,'2017-01-01',10000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(4,2,'2016-02-02',15000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(5,2,'2016-01-01',9000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(6,2,'2017-01-01',12000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(7,3,'2016-08-01',1000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(8,3,'2017-03-30',15000);
INSERT INTO Venda VALUES(9,3,'2017-09-08',25000);

SELECT A.VENDEDOR_NOME, MAX(venda_valor) 
FROM Vendedor as A 
LEFT JOIN Venda as B ON (A.VENDEDOR_ID = B.VENDEDOR_ID) 
WHERE B.vendedor_data between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select v.vendedor_nome, ve.*
from venedor v left join
     (select ve.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ve.vendedor_id order by ve.venda_valor desc) as seqnum
      from venda ve
     ) ve
     on ve.vendedor_id = v.vendedor_id and ve.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: it worked just fine. i just added a desc to the order by function. thank you so much